# HTML5 Web Workers - How to share work between threads

Tags: javascript, html, web-worker

I'm pretty new when it comes to JS but I've had a stab at some basic multi-threading after researching the Web Workers API. My attempt below is to abstract the logic for determining the next work unit aka sendWorkUnit() and then to use it when starting the workers and during their message handler to ensure that they keep getting work until the job is finished.

I thought this approach was reasonable but I'm suspicious I've got the design wrong. Why? because I soon realized that I'm not closing each worker once the job is finished, so, I tried to modify sendWorkUni() as follows:

```
function sendWorkUnit(worker) {
  if (workCount < testData.length) {
    worker.postMessage(testData[workCount++]);
  } else {
    worker.terminate();
  }
}
```

However, when I make this change the whole thing blows up and I only get back the first 4 elements of my array. Any explanation or pointers would be much appreciated!

Manager.js

```
window.onload = function() {
  var numWorkers = 5,
      workers = [],
  testData = ['f', 'o', 'o', 'b', 'a', 'h'],
  workCount = 0,
  ol = document.querySelector('#output');

//Spawn some workers
for (var i = 0; i < numWorkers; i++) {
  var worker = new Worker('worker.js');
  worker.addEventListener('message', function(e) {
    displayWorkUnit(e);
    sendWorkUnit(worker);
  }, false);
  workers.push(worker);
}

//Start the workers
for (var i = 0, l = workers.length; i < l; i++) {
  sendWorkUnit(workers[i]);
}  

//Send next unit
function sendWorkUnit(worker) {
  if (workCount < testData.length) {
    worker.postMessage(testData[workCount++]);
  } 
}

//Display each worker's output
function displayWorkUnit(e) {
  var li = document.createElement('li');
  li.innerHTML = e.data;
  ol.appendChild(li);
}
```

}

Worker.js

```
self.addEventListener('message', function(e) {
  postMessage(e.data.toUpperCase());
}, false);
```

Comment: I cannot reproduce this with your code, I'm getting `F
O
O
B
A
H` correctly. Can you make a demo maybe?

Comment: Are you using the modified sendNextUnit()? The code I posted seems to work but I don't think it's using multi-threading correctly, which is exposed when you run it with the modified sendNextUnit().

Comment: Ah, in Opera I had to make the worker message explicitly asynchronous by adding a timeout; now I'm getting an error. Could you post the exceptions you get in your error console please?